# Returning only the positive result's percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, informix

I need to get the percentage of the column "is_backed_up" in the SQL table called syslogs.

I got the statement to work; however, I need only the percentage of the positive result, '1' being backed up and '0' being unbacked up.
When I run:

```
Select (Count(is_backed_up)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From syslogs))
From syslogs 
Group By is_backed_up;
```

I get:

```
 (expression)    
 37.79527559055    
 62.20472440945
```

I only want to see the 62% value, which is the backed up value.

I am using Informix v12.1 on a Unix box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are undoubtedly many ways to do it, but this should do the job:

```
SELECT 100 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syslogs)
  FROM syslogs
 WHERE is_backed_up = 1;
```

This counts the rows which are marked as backed up, and divides that by the total number of rows in the syslogs table (and multiplies by 100 to get the percentage).

There is nothing here that depends on Informix syntax specifically.